# sum property of consecutive numbers

Tags: algorithm, math, sum

Suppose we have a list of numbers like [6,5,4,7,3]. How can we tell that the array contains consecutive numbers? One way is ofcourse to sort them or we can find the minimum and maximum. But can we determine based on the sum of the elements ? E.g. in the example above, it is 25. Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: In the example you used, the sum is 25.  The sum of [6,5,5,6,3] is also 25.  The sum has nowhere near enough information to recover much about the original elements.

Comment: The sum of `n` consecutive numbers starting at `a` will be `(n + a - 1)(n + a) / 2 - a(a - 1) / 2`. Then you'd just make sure there were no duplicates, I suppose.

Comment: @minitech: Oh, I see what you mean. However, checking for duplicates should be `O(n*log n)` worst case as well, so we can just sort

Comment: @NiklasB.: shouldn't checking for duplicates be O(n)?  One pass to get bounds, then flip a bit.  If max-min+1 > number of elements then you can't be consecutive anyway [conditioned on the sum, that is], so memory storage should be O(n) too.

Comment: @NiklasB.: If you use a hash, won't it be `O(n)`? (Sorry, I'm not good with this big-O thing.)

Comment: @DSM: Flip a bit? What if there are three occurences of the same number?

Comment: @minitech: Hashes are not deterministic, but yeah, it should be `O(n)` on average. Worst case is `Ω(n²)`, though

Comment: @NiklasB.: as soon as you need to flip it back from 1 to 0, you know they're not unique, don't you?

Comment: @DSM: Right :/ Sure, that seems like a sensible approach. Of course we can also just use an `O(n)` sorting algorithm, but that might have a higher constant factor (some testing would be required)

Comment: @DonRoby yeah right didn't notice that. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The sum of elements by itself is not enough.

Instead you could check for:

- All elements being unique.

and either:

- Difference between min and max being right

or

- Sum of all elements being right.

#### Approach 1

Sort the list and check the first element and last element.

In general this is O( n log(n) ), but if you have a limited data set you can sort in O( n ) time using [counting sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) or [radix sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort).

#### Approach 2

Pass over the data to get the highest and lowest elements.

As you pass through, add each element into a hash table and see if that element has now been added twice. This is more or less O( n ).

#### Approach 3

To save storage space (hash table), use an approximate approach.

Pass over the data to get the highest and lowest elements.

As you do, implement an algorithm which will with high (read User defined) probability determine that each element is distinct. Many such algorithms exist, and are in use in Data Mining. Here's a link to a [paper](http://www.pittsburgh.intel-research.net/people/gibbons/talks-surveys/Distinct-Values-Estimation-over-Data-Streams-PBGibbons.pdf) describing different approaches.

Comment: Do we really need to check the sum if we know that min and max are correct, the element count is correct and that there are no duplicates? I think not

Comment: @NiklasB. that's right, as long as the difference between max and min is the number of elements minus 1, (and all are unique), then we are okay. (if you know what range you are looking for, i.e. 1 to 10, then verifying min==1 and max==10 works). edited first sentence to clear up any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

The numbers in the array would be consecutive if the difference between the max and the minimum number of the array is equal to n-1 provided numbers are unique ( where n is the size of the array ). And ofcourse minimum and maximum number can be calculated in O(n).

Comment: That is a necessary condition for the numbers being consecutive, but not a sufficient one. e.g. [1,1,4,4]

Comment: i guess this is for some  ongoing  programming contest. http://www.codechef.com/SEP12

Comment: @AkashdeepSaluja: What problem is this?

Comment: @NiklasB. http://www.codechef.com/SEP12/problems/CHEFTOWN  This logic is used in the question ( but in the question numbers in array are unique ).